# Output raster from geostatistical layer to match template raster: why is there an extra row of NoData cells?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, spatial-analyst, extents, kriging

I have a geostatistical layer created using ordinary kriging and the `Create Geostatistical Layer` tool in Model Builder. I am trying to output this layer to a raster that matches a target raster using the `GA Layer to Grid` tool.  I have used the target raster to set the `Snap Raster`, `Cell Size`, and `Processing Extent` environment variables and various logical combinations of these variables.  However, the raster that is output has one additional row at the top when compared to the target raster.  This row is filled with `NoData` values.

Differences are highlighted in ***bold italics***

### The target raster has these dimensions:

> Columns_and_Rows: 110, ***166***
>   Cell_Size: 0.11559105, 0.11559105
>   Extent:
>
> > Top     ***49.359975678***
> >     Left  -129.652945807
> >     Right -116.937930333
> >     Bottom  30.1718614184
>
> Spatial_Reference: CS_WGS_1984

### The output raster has these:

> Columns_and_Rows: 110, ***167***
>   Cell_Size: 0.11559105, 0.11559105
>   Extent:
>
> > Top     ***49.4755667278***
> >      Left  -129.652945807
> >      Right -116.937930333
> >      Bottom  30.1718614184
>
> Spatial_Reference: CS_WGS_1984

Why does my raster have an extra row (and therefore the wrong Extent) and how can I fix this?

Comment: If environment is set as you said try simple map calculator on output, e.g. output*1

Comment: @FelixIP, is the idea behind your suggestion to use the Raster Calculator to drop the NoData row?  In that case, a raster clip operation can work as well.  I prefer not to have an extra step in the model if possible.  I should be able to output a raster that matches my template, so ideally someone can help me figure that out. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Clip, yeah right. Good luck in finding the reason, I hit this wall multiple times

Comment: @FelixIP I was actually able to resolve this by setting all relevant environment variables and tool parameters at once.  See my answer below.

Comment: It means they were not set up as your stated on your post

Comment: No, as I said in the question I had actually set all of the _Environment_ variables in various combinations but didn't _also_ set the `Cell Size` in the tool.  For some reason that made a difference though in theory the tool should take (and shows it does!) the `Cell Size` from the environment.  puzzling.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to resolve my problem by setting additional variables both for the environment and the tool.  Specifically, I added the target raster as an element in the model.  I then used the `Connect` tool to link it to the `GA Layer to Grid` model object and set: 1) `Snap Raster` environment variable, 2) `Extent` environment variable, 3) `Cell Size` *tool* parameter and 4) `Cell Size` environment variable.  I don't know if the order has any effect (it shouldn't), but this process gave me output rasters with the proper resolution and extent matching the target raster.